# How to read two argument separated by "/" in command line input in java?

Tags: java

I have the input as  07/12 on my command line how can I use this two argument as args[0] and args[1] to convert into month and day

```
int month = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
int day = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
```

The error I am having is "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "07/12"

Comment: Well you can't use that as two arguments, because it's one argument. Either you need to split that one argument into two strings (e.g. with `String.split`) or provide two arguments on the command line instead.

Comment: Yes, there's no magic parsing of CLI arguments, use a split or a scanner here

Comment: So you typed in 07/12 and it's taking that whole thing as arg[0] but failing to convert it to an int.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's because the date you are passing is all contained in the `args[0]`. Try this

```
String[] date = args[0].split("/");
int month = Integer.parseInt(date[0]);
int day = Integer.parseInt(date[1]);
```

Answer (score 1):

It's looking at the whole string. You want to split the string then parseInteger.